# Cannot read property 'value' of null input field?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

Whenever I type on `input` field, I am getting the following error:-

> Cannot read property 'value' of null

I have one form in which I have one `input` field *search value* when I try to type anything I am getting the error.

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/6836mkjx3) is my code.

The issues on this function

```
handleInputFieldChange = (event, name) => {
    this.setState(preState => ({
      ...preState,
      form: {
        ...preState.form,
        [name]: event.target.value
      }
    }));
  };
```

Comment: you can give an attribute of name to your input like: <input name=".." />  and in your event handler just get the name and value both from the target and do not pass the name and set it in the state llike:  form: {
        ...preState.form,
        [e.target.name]: e.target.value
      }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a warning from React lib itself, which basically guides you how to solve this.

> Warning: This synthetic event is reused for performance reasons. If
>   you're seeing this, you're accessing the property `target` on a
>   released/nullified synthetic event. **This is set to null. If you must
>   keep the original synthetic event around, use `event.persist()`**

So the fix is get a reference of the target object in a local variable like below.

```
handleInputFieldChange = (event, name) => {
    const { target } = event;
    this.setState(preState => ({
      ...preState,
      form: {
        ...preState.form,
        [name]: target.value
      }
    }));
  };
```

This is only happened when you are using **updater** function with `setState` method. They asked to use `event.persist()`, but in my application, just take the reference of the `target` object to use it inside the **update function**, which works 100%.

Checkout the doc of [Event Pooling](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html#event-pooling)

> The SyntheticEvent is pooled. This means that the SyntheticEvent
>   object will be reused and all properties will be nullified after the
>   event callback has been invoked. This is for performance reasons. As
>   such, you cannot access the event in an asynchronous way.
>
> If you want to access the event properties in an asynchronous way, you
>   should call event.persist() on the event, which will remove the
>   synthetic event from the pool and allow references to the event to be
>   retained by user code.

Comment: still an  issue please try to type anything on input field